# How can I multiplex the outputs of an XBEE and a MAX485's?

Tags: digital-logic, serial, logic-gates, multiplexer, digital-communications

I have a microcontroller that gets fed with 8-bit commands that either come through wires (using the RS-485 standard) or by the RX pin of an XBEE (without using actual switches) I want to multiplex them somehow in order to automatically receive the right command coming from the right source. I tried using some logic-gate circuitry but it only works if the data is coming from the XBEE. I think the main problem is that the idle state of the XBEE is on 3.3V and the idle state of the MAX485 is 0V. [image: My implementation]
Does anyone have any idea how I could make it work? Also, another problem would be converting the 3.3V logic of the XBEE to a 5V logic, I thought of using a level converter IC, but I would like to know if it's possible only by using a transistor. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Usually to multiplex signals you want to use a multiplexer. Those aren't expensive. However, I think, you want some functionality like automatic multiplexing. That's difficult without analyzing the protocol in depth. Someone has to decide where to take the input from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, for the multiplexing you should use a multiplexer instead of fiddling with single gates. You only get race conditions, hence glitches etc. from trying this with simple logic. However, if I understand correctly, this is not the core of your problem.

You want some device to decide which input should be routed to your I/O. This isn't easy, because having two inputs leads to four possible states. No signal, a signal from either input or simultaneous signals from both inputs. In most cases the solution is to use two serial IOs at your microcontroller, because then you get rid of all such problems.

What is necessary to do it without spending another serial port?

You could trigger a latch with both inputs and have one of them inverted. The output of the latch represents the input where the last „non idle“ level was received. The output of the latch then can trigger a mux.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fb31Bh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, this doesn't help you in the fourth case, when two I/O-signals arrive at the same time. Then you have to decide how to react on such collisions.

Edit

One option to deal with this priorization problem is to put another D-Latch after the R/S-Latch.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT7TNc.png)</sup>

This allows the μC to control when to switch between input signals. As long as the output from the μC is high, either incoming signal can trigger the mux to change. The μC's duty is then to set the control pin to low as long as it wants to read the incoming data. At the end of the transmission the μC releases the pin to high again and the autoselect mechanism is reactivated.

You have to make sure that the propagation delay of the AND and OR-gate together is greater than the delay of the RS. Otherwise the wrong signal will be latched through the D-latch.

Still, if simultaneous transmissions aren't ruled out, you will face incomplete transmissions after releasing the gate pin.

Concerning the level shift, there are lots of solutions on the web and in most cases they are more cumbersome to build up and in any case more expensive than an level converter IC. Do you have a reason to do it discrete or is it just for learning?

Comment: I slightly modified the logic of the RS485 and now the idle state is on 5V, so the multiplexing problem at the microcontroller drastically reduced (https://i.imgur.com/FT0ohBC.jpg). I think this might work, although I still have the 3.3V to 5V problem to handle - the logic gates are in 5V logic. I will first try to use a common base/collector transistor circuit for this and if it doesn't work, I'll buy a logic converter IC. Thanks!